# Can I run `apt-get purge --auto-remove`?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

Is `apt-get purge --auto-remove packagename` a valid command?

Or, does it have to be `apt-get remove --purge --auto-remove packagename`?

The Ubuntu manpage for apt-get (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/apt-get.8.html) only mentions using the --auto-remove option "If the command is either install or remove...", so I was wondering if it could also be used with the purge command, since that is just a shortcut for the remove command with the --purge option.

Thank you.

Comment: why `--auto-remove`?

Comment: If the --auto-remove option is used when removing a package then it will remove dependencies of the package that are no longer needed. Kind of like how `apt-get autoremove` checks for and will "remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no longer needed" (from above-linked manpage).

Comment: If you examine the manpage, you will notice that autoremove can be used as a command (autoremove) or as an option (--auto-remove) during a command. However, it is only mentioned as an option in the context of an install or remove command, so I wondered if the option could also be used with a purge command. Using the option is just kind of a way to shortcut it, instead of running two separate commands.

Comment: You can also use `apt-get autoremove --purge`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, those commands are valid. Moreover, they are equivalent because `purge` is equivalent with `remove --purge` (see `man apt-get`).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I did figure that if the first was valid, then it would be equivalent to the second. I just wanted to make sure that the first was indeed valid.